# Prevent a device from doing an action multiple times

Tags: php

So I have a web application which is going to collect people's opinion (People have to choose option 1 or option 2). I don't want anyone to submit their opinion twice or more, which makes me think an opinion is more popular when it isn't, so I think of several ways, but they all have their disadvantage:

- Check user's IP address: user can change their IP easily by using web proxy or something like that.
- Check user's HWID like what I did on another desktop application: Seem like it's impossible with php

Can you suggest me a way which is the most effective for my web application's issue? The ideal solution is having only one vote per device, but I have no idea how to do it with PHP.

Edit: Please give me your advice on this: does cookie work with web proxy? If the application stored a cookie, then the user open the website with web proxy or simply use private browsing, is the cookie still there? If it is, a combination between IP address and cookie may works.

Comment: IP address has the reverse effect, too.  If multiple people are behind a NAT, only one can vote.

Comment: You could use cookies, but they are also editable sadly

Comment: You can't prevent this, per se, but you can make it harder for them to vote multiple times.  Maybe require them to login first.  Most users won't really be arsed to have to register with their email a 2nd time.

Comment: Exactly, you cant be 100% sure, but you can make it harder to do and therefore its less likely to happen.

Comment: There is ABSOLUTELY NO way to ensure every visitor is a unique individual. You just do the best you can. That is why many sites require you to sign in with a Facebook ID because they assume every human has a Facebook ID and that nobody has more than one Facebook ID.

Comment: I think you should look at `EVERCOOKIE` it is a javascript API available that produces extremely persistent cookies in a browser. http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: @kainaw: Personally, if a site *requires* Facebook login, I don't use that site.  Though, that's similar to my argument, where a user *can* re-register but most won't care enough to do so.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Stackoverflow also requires facebook/google/other ids.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. After reading the comment section, I have an idea and edited my question, please read it again and give me your advice, thanks.

Comment: @RNKushwaha: I use my own OpenID (hosted on my own server) to login to StackOverflow :-D  Also, StackOverflow doesn't *require* it.  You can login to StackOverflow without any other account.

Comment: @user76757 Do you want one vote *per device* or *per person*?

Comment: @idmean one vote per device is what I want, but if it's impossible, I will do the best I can.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent accidental multiple submissions, require a login and save the vote in a database, or create a random unique ID that is tied to the user's session, and save that one with the vote, rejecting votes whose IDs already exist, or save a flag in the session that the user already voted.

You could use ever-/super-cookies to make deliberately faking votes harder, but you cannot prevent them unless you have some means to verify an identity and ensure that no person can have multiple identities, e.g. ID cards issued by the government with functions for eCommerce and e(Whatever), social security numbers. However, you will have to interface with an institution performing the verification for you.

And ever-/super-cookies and browser fingerprinting are vulnerable to the use of multiple browsers and break when facing paranoid users.

If you want to prevent multiple deliberate votes with low security and reliability, you could establish an identity like on StackExchange / StackOverflow, i.e. reputation-based, and prevent votes until someone has gained some reputation level.

Or you could require phone-/account-/credit-card-/payments-based verification with low level of confidence (e.g. send SMS text message with verification code to phone number, Facebook, Google, Amazon, PayPal, Stripe...) - people can have multiple phones, accounts, credit/debit cards etc.

In the end, there is no easy-to-use system for identity verification that prevents multiple identities with high confidence (that I know of).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, I really need an easy-to-use system to do my job. Please give me your advice on this: does cookie work with web proxy? If the application stored a cookie, then the user open the website with web proxy or simply use private browsing, is the cookie still there? If it is, a combination between IP address and cookie may works.

Comment: A regular cookie should work with web proxies but will be removed (or not stored at all) when exiting private browsing. It may be possible to use some super-cookies to circumvent this, e.g. the [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) persistence mechanism found in browsers - it is kept across private browsing sessions (but may be fixed sometime soon). As others have said, relying on IP addresses is bad - it may change during a session (when the ISP disconnects you, or when you switch from wireless to 3G), and may be shared between multiple users.